# random text string

Tags: javascript

I am fooling around with this function that says if you leave this text box blank than print the error code. if its not blank that print one of the text strings. The error code is working but I cannot get it to print any of the text strings. I think the problem is somewhere in returning the random selection to the html doc, I am not sure how to syntax this. 
When you click the button it executes the function

```
function button() {
    var a = "Punf";
    var b = "Relcken";
    var c = "Checks in the mail";
    var d = "Thae said";
    var e = "Drorself";
    var f = "Thertions";
    var g = "Don stupid";
    var err = "You think you are smarter than this website? Your not!"

    if (document.getElementById('ask').value == "") {
        document.getElementById('answer').innerHTML = err;
    }

    if (document.getElementById('ask').value == !"") {
        var qoute = (a, b, c, d, e, f, g);
        var maxQuote = quote.length;
        var randQuote = Math.floor(Math.random() * maxQuote);
        return quote(randQuote);
        document.getElementById('answer').innerHTML = a;
    }
}
```

I have got it down to here but I am still having issues and I am not sure why, Thanks for pointing out my rookie mistakes I need to take a step back and look at it with fresh eyes more.

```
if (document.getElementById('ask').value == ""){

document.getElementById('answer').innerHTML = err;

}
        var quote = [a,b,c,d,e,f,g];
        var maxQuote = quote.length;
        var randQuote = Math.floor(Math.random()*maxQuote);
        document.getElementById('answer').value = quote[randQuote];



    }
```

Comment: You do realize that because you have a return statement the innerHTML of "answer" is never going to get set?

Comment: You've spelled your var `quote` and `qoute`...

Comment: Spelling mistake in variable declaration. Also, use != "" not == !""

Comment: Contest: I spot five major problems with this code. How many do you see?

Comment: @PeterOlson: 1) naming convention, 2) too many, unnecessary variables, 3) incorrect comparison, 4) incorrect array literal, 5) some parts of the code will never be executed, 6) this _not executed part_ makes something dummy and does not need any calculations, 7) the `button()` function not always return value. Anything else?

Comment: @Tadeck No, those were all the ones I was thinking of, and then some.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You have made a typo.**

Change line:

```
var qoute = (a,b,c,d,e,f,g);
```

into the following:

```
var quote = [a,b,c,d,e,f,g];
```

and this line:

```
return quote(randQuote);
```

into this line:

```
return quote[randQuote];
```

and tell me if it fixed the problem.

Answer (score 2):

What is `== !''`?

```
if (something equals not-a-blank-string)
```

?

What's the "not" of a blank string?

That should be `!== ''` instead.

Comment: You are wrong - `== !''` is not the same as `!==''`. The first is actually the same as `== true` and I believe you understand the difference between `== true` and `!== ''`?

Comment: No, I don't.  What's the inverse of an empty string? A full string? Full of what? Nulls? 0s? random characters? Killer African bees? It's a syntactically horrible construct.

Comment: Horrible or not, this is sometimes used (in more meaningful situations, though). Have you seen eg. `!!a` (where `a` is some integer)? You would probably say " _it is opposite of the opposite of some integer, it is horrible construct_ ", but for some it is just conversion from integer to boolean.

Comment: I was trying to state if the value is not null, does it not work this way?

Comment: @EdwardNickAJubrey If you want to compare something to null, use the constructs "a == null" or "a != null".  '' is not the same as null:  it signifies an empty (zero-length) string.

Answer (score 1):

change

```
document.getElementById('ask').value == !""
```

to

```
document.getElementById('ask').value != ""
```

Answer (score 1):

Point 1:  array syntax is with `[]` and not `()`

```
var qoute = [a,b,c,d,e,f,g];
...
quote[randQuote];
```

Point 2:  return will prevent the execution of the last line

```
    return quote(randQuote);
    document.getElementById('answer').innerHTML = a; // never executed.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var qoute = (a,b,c,d,e,f,g);
```

should be:

```
var qoute = [a,b,c,d,e,f,g];
```

basically:

```
var qoute = (a,b,c,d,e,f,g);
```

becomes:

```
var qoute = g; // commma operator
```

This:

```
if (document.getElementById('ask').value == !""){
```

should just be:

```
if (document.getElementById('ask').value) { // value has something, is not null or "" <-- empty
```